# Flashing window in gnu screen

Tags: gnu-screen, unix-utils

I really like `gnu screen` but there is a problem in my environment when I use it.

Examle:

```
username@domain:/var/www$ l
Display all 130 possibilities? (y or n)
```

when you click `[Tab]` to perform autocompletion there is a screen flashing for a very short period of time(looks like white screen but I can see it for a very-very short time).

There isn't any problems with that when I execute the same action in normal/non-screen environment.

This is what my `.screenrc` looks like:

```
attrcolor b ".I"
termcapinfo xterm 'Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm'
defbce "on"
term screen-256color-bce
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

add `set bell-style none` to the readline init file, ~/.inputrc

> bell-style
>
> Controls what happens when
> Readline wants to ring the terminal
> bell. If set to ‘none’, Readline never
> rings the bell. If set to ‘visible’,
> Readline uses a visible bell if one is
> available. If set to ‘audible’ (the
> default), Readline attempts to ring
> the terminal's bell.the terminal's bell.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Init-File

[edit: thanks Fedyashev Nikita]

Comment: I had the same problem but the only difference is that Readline init file is stored in ~/.inputrc file(at least in Ubuntu). So I've added it there and now it works fine! thank you

Comment: Using debian, I set this option in `/etc/inputrc`

Answer (score 28):

Just add `vbell "off"` to your `.screenrc`

Comment: +1, prefer this method.  I just want to turn the visual bell off completely.  It's pretty annoying...

Answer (score 1):

The shell "prints" the bell character when it asks "Display all possibilities?"  Normally this would beep but something is translating it to a screen flash.

As a wild guess, try changing the `termcapinfo` line to

```
termcapinfo xterm 'Co#256:AF=\E[38;5;%dm'
```

That removes the `AB` section, which I think means "audio bell".

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above solution myself which didn't work.

However, the following solution from Thr4wn worked.
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/trying-to-use-gnu-screen-backspace-makes-screen-flash-685321/

The feature is called "visual bell".

here are applicable properties you can set in your ~/.screenrc file

```
vbell_msg "bell: window ~%" # Message for visual bell
vbellwait 2 # Seconds to pause the screen for visual bell
vbell off # Turns visual bell off
```

[edit] Forgot to say that the last line seems to be all it needs.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence `Ctrl-a`, `Ctrl-g` is quick way to toggle the "visual bell" in `screen`.

Comment: It says "switched to audible bell." when you do this.  I wonder if the server beeps whenever I hit <tab> too many times.  Maybe I will practice my Morse code and see if anyone responds.